# What mean an url with character ":"

Tags: javascript, redirect

I have this URL in my console network but I don't understand what they do .. What mean "avg:insert"
https://grder.eu/1253/**avg:insert**

Comment: [tag:javascript] and [tag:redirect] don't seem to fit this question. Please choose tags that are actually relevant!

Comment: `:` is a [valid character](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1547940/3082296) in URL. Depends entirely on how *grder.eu*
 uses it. For example, wikipedia uses it to seperate sections and subsections: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Contents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A colon in the path component has no special meaning in URL syntax. It's just a character.

If there is any special meaning given to it, it is given that meaning in site-specific code.